# Excel: Memory limit while using Fuzzy Lookup

Tags: excel

(Excel 2016 32-bit)

I'm using Fuzzy Lookup to identify duplicate customers I have in my system. I'm using 3 fields: Address1, Address2, and Address3. My table consists of 90000 rows. Number of matches is set to 5 and the Similarity Threshold is at 90%.  Fuzzy Lookup ends up hitting the Excel Memory Limit when around 79000 rows have completed. Sometimes it errors and other times it crashes.

Any thoughts on what I can do to avoid hitting the Excel Memory Limit?

Comment: If something is too much for Excel then the next logical solution would be an SQL Server: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/fuzzy-searches-sql-server/?utm_source=simpletalk&utm_medium=pubemail&utm_content=20170307-slota2&utm_term=simpletalkmain

Comment: Thanks, @Ralph. I assumed this would be the case. Was just trying to avoid that route. And thank you for the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered an easy fix to this without utilizing SQL.

**Create an output table prior to running Fuzzy Lookup!**

It really is that simple. Create a table, format your columns, select Cells(2, 1), and run Fuzzy Lookup.

Answer (score 3):

Seems this problem maybe the symptom of a bug when inserting the results into an Excel 'Table' object (other wise know as list object in vba). The symptom, as the add-in makes more matches, the memory consumed by the process steadily climbs until (on a 32bit system) the 2GB memory limit is hit and an 'Out of memory exception' is throw. Expected behaviour should be for the memory consumption to remain at a constant level once matches are being generated.

**The solution in my case,** don't use an Excel 'Table' object as the Fuzzy Lookup output, the safest option would be a blank worksheet.

Comment: It's the opposite. If you don't create the list object the 'Out of memory exception' is thrown. The list object prevents it and memory consumption remains constant.

Comment: Our experience/solutions seems to at odds. In your case, when you experienced the issue, were you outputting the data into a worksheet populated with other data (formulas, formatting, etc.), or a blank sheet?

Comment: I was outputting the data into a blank worksheet with no formulas, formatting, etc. when I was experiencing errors. I monitored the RAM being consumed and it kept growing until the limit was reached. I also upgraded to 64 bit and tried again with the same outcome. Once I created a table / list object for my output the issue no longer occurred and memory consumption remained constant.

Answer (score 0):

After searching forums without any luck I kept digging in further and believe to have found out where the issue lies.

When you are converting your columns or making tables, if you are selecting the whole column, it creates a table object for the whole column of that sheet and then when you run the lookup it gets into an endless search because it is trying to match each value with every value in the other table.

**Solution:**
When converting columns to table(Ctrl+L), do not select the whole column until the end of spreadsheet. See pictures.

[image: IMG]

Comment: This was not part of the issue experienced. The original table had 90000+ unique records which were not a result of accidentally selecting the whole column instead of a specified range.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue of fuzzy look up taking ages to finish. The problem was my table definition. I selected the entire column instead of selecting only the data rows. After only selecting the data to create the table, fuzzylook up was much faster. Hope this helps others looking for a solution